# Can we support our high and low notes while singing with throat

Tags: voice

I have some questions to ask you guys. Can you support your notes and have resonance when you sing with your throat ? How do I use chest voice and how do I use my diaphragm? People just say “use your diaphragm” but how ???

Comment: Does "guys" refer to specifically male singers, or generally the whole Music SE community?

Answer (score 2):

1. Singing from the diaphragm is hard to explain, but it kind of refers to using pressure from your stomach area to push air out of you, as opposed to tensing up your ribs/chest/throat. You should avoid putting lots of pressure on your throat as it is unsustainable without the proper training.
2. Chest voice refers to when you sing without going "into your head" or using falsetto or a "mixed voice". It is easy to think of as your normal speaking range, from your lowest note up to around where your voice breaks.
3. You should not put all of the pressure from singing in your throat. Your chest is much more supported and can withstand a lot more pressure, and is therefore much more sustainable and less painful.

Try breathing in as far as you can, by expanding your stomach and not moving your shoulders, and breathing out using the same technique. Using this breathing technique to sing will make everything much more comfortable.

Also, you can absolutely sing from your diaphragm in order to hit both high and low notes.

There are many free online tutorials on how to sing correctly, but if you are struggling or just want proper feedback, I would recommend hiring a professional to coach you. There's only so much good that free online help can get you.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you support your notes and have resonance when you sing with your throat ?

Yes for short term, No for long term. ie) Your vocal chord will get tired after couple of minutes of singing when you support it from your throat. Most resonance will happen in head  while pitch happens in the larynx and most support has to come from lower abdomen and optionally little from upper abdomen.

> How do I use chest voice

Chest voice is the notes that you create which are on the low range pitches of your total voice range, and head voice is the notes that you create which are on the higher range pitches of your total voice range.

> how do I use my diaphragm? People just say “use your diaphragm” but how ???

Try touching just below the front side lower ribs with your finger and take a deep breath(breathe as low as possible), you will feel a rubber pushing out below from the lower ribs, this is diaphragm, we try to maintain this expanded/pushed-out when singing/exhaling using lower abs (you can sense this part engages when you cough), and additionally support this by keeping the chest lifted up and lowering the shoulders allowing the ribs to expand as we sing/exhale. It may take a couple of weeks to get this correct after practicing daily singing with this technique.